# Factoring Integers, question on Wiki algorithm

Tags: algorithms, factoring, prime-factorization

I have questions on the integer factorization algorithm described on [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorization). The Wiki description is heavy English and I translated it so it's more symbolic.  My question is if this translation makes sense and follows in a **bold** questions section.

Wiki says for finding a divisor such that $(mod(a,b) = 0) \land a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$ an algorithm is followed.  The repeated application of the algorithm to $b$ and $d = \frac a b$ gives the complete factorization of $a$ or decides if $a$ is prime.

It states in summary that the algorithm should only test $B_{test} = \{b \in \mathbb{Z} : 1 \lt b \land b^2 \le a\}$.  The claim is that if there is a divisor $d$ such that form (1):

$((mod(a,d) = 0) \land (d^2 > a) \land d \in \mathbb{Z}) \implies (b = \frac a d \land (mod(a, b)=0) \land(b^2 \le a))$

Wiki states that if $b$ is tested in increasing order the first divisor $b$ is a prime number and for the cofactor $d$ this form (2) holds $((d = \frac a b) \land (mod(d,z) = 0) \land (d^2 \gt a) \land (d,z \in \mathbb{Z}))\implies  (z \ge b)$.  This part is confusing and I will explain in questions.  For complete factorization, the algorithm is continued finding form (3) $(mod(d, b_2) = 0) \land (d \ge b) \land (d \ge \sqrt r)$.  Finally, as an optimization, only prime values for $b$ need be tested using a generated table from a sieve.

**QUESTIONS**

1. Is this an accurate description of the general algorithm?  Appreciate guidance.
2. Is Form (2) correct?  I tested it on a number and it was false.
3. Is there additional algebra proving $b^2 \le a$?
4. I provide the following examples for repeated application. Are they accurate?

For example the recursive factorization algorithm $F(a, 1)$:

$
    F(a, b)= 
\begin{cases}
    (),& \text{if } b^2\gt a\\
    (b, \frac a b, F(a, b + 1)),& \text{if } mod(a,b) = 0 \\
    F(a, b + 1), & \text{otherwise } \\
\end{cases}
$

$
    F(a, b)= 
\begin{cases}
    (),& \text{if } b \gt a\\
    (b, F(a, b + 1)),& \text{if } mod(a,b) = 0 \\
    F(a, b + 1), & \text{otherwise } \\
\end{cases}
$

For example just prime factorization $P(a, 2)$:

$
    P(a, b)= 
\begin{cases}
    (a),& \text{if } b^2\gt a\\
    (b, P(\frac a b, b)),& \text{if } mod(a,b) = 0 \\
    P(b + 1, \frac a b), & \text{otherwise } \\
\end{cases}
$